# VB.NET Add namespace to existing

Tags: .net, xml

I want this as XML:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:sear="http://eur-lex.europa.eu/search">
<soap:Header>
</soap:Header>
</soap:Envelope>
```

my Code:

```
Dim D As New Xml.XmlDocument
Dim soapEnvelope As Xml.XmlElement = D.AppendChild(D.CreateElement("soap", "Envelope", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"))
soapEnvelope.SetAttribute("xmlns:sear", "http://eur-lex.europa.eu/search")
Dim soapHeader As Xml.XmlElement = soapEnvelope.AppendChild(D.CreateElement("soap:Header"))
```

But the Header Element has no "soap" prefix.

its not:

```
<soap:Header>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried: `Dim soapHeader As Xml.XmlElement = soapEnvelope.AppendChild(D.CreateElement("soap", "Header", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"))`? You could also use `XNamespace` as explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace(v=vs.110).aspx and/or Xml literals

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating an element with the name `soap:Header` do this:

```
Dim soapHeader As Xml.XmlElement = 
    soapEnvelope.AppendChild(
        D.CreateElement("soap", "Header", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"))
```

You could also use `XNamespace` as explained [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and maybe even use Xml literals.